# glfw non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Tags: c++, glfw

i keep getting `non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`

i dont know why its not working.

it works if Resize function is global

minimal example:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
class test {
public:
    test(){}
    ~test(){}
    void resize(GLFWwindow* window, int new_width, int new_height) {}
}resizer;

int main(){
    auto newwindow = glfwCreateWindow(1, 1, "test", NULL, NULL);
    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(newwindow, resizer.resize);

   return 0;
}
```

the initial problem got kinda solved using static as the function but this created diferent errors in what i want to do here is the simplified problem the problem:

```
//rough replication of lib functions cannot change these
typedef void(* windowsizefun)(int,int);
void setWindowSizeCallback(windowsizefun fun){}

//the problem
class windowhandler{
    private:
        int width, height;
        static void resize(int new_width, int new_height) {
            width =new_width; height =new_height; //error
        }
    public:
        test(){
            width =100; height =100;
            setWindowSizeCallback(windowhandler::resize);
        }            
}

int main(){
    windowhandler newWindow();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Enter the error message in the search box at the top of this page.

Comment: i cant find any related to gflw callbacks

Comment: s/`window.Resize`/`&window::Resize` and make sure that `Resize()` is declared `static`.

Comment: @jeana glfw has very little to do with it. It's a more general problem.

Comment: @user0042 `a storage class may not be specified here` wen i make resize static, and `window.setResize(&window::Resize);` gives `:: must be a class or namespace name`

Comment: @jeana Provide a [MCVE] that reproduces your error in [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47605894/edit) please.

Comment: class Window{ void setResize(GLFWwindowsizefun {resize)glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(window, resize);}
 void Resize(GLFWwindow* _window, int new_width, int new_height){glViewport(0, 0, new_width, new_height);} } #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>  int main(){ Window window; window.setResize(window.Resize); return 0;}

Comment: @user0042 ok i changed it so its easy to replicate

Answer (score 0):

Your function pointer doesn't match the declaration that's needed to pass into `glfwSetWindowSizeCallback()`.

It must be a `static` function, and the scope operator `::` needs to be applied correctly:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
class test {
public:
    test(){}
    ~test(){}
    static void resize(GLFWwindow* window, int new_width, int new_height) {}
 // ^^^^^^
}  /*resizer*/;
// ^^^^^^^^^^^ No need for this.

int main(){
    auto newwindow = glfwCreateWindow(1, 1, "test", NULL, NULL);
    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(newwindow, test::resize);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you this works, can you explain why this is the case? looking into the typedef of GLFWwindowsizefun did not reveal it needed to be static and if the function is global it works as not static

Comment: wait i have an other problem now, the static function cant use class variables

Comment: Looks like you need to specialize a `GLFWwindow` class to create an actual instance of `test`. Refer to the GLFW documentation how to do that.

Comment: what? why? this hole thing makes no sense

Comment: @jeana I'm not an GLFW expert, but that looks like you're interfacing with a plain C-API. You need to encapsulate the `GLFWwindow*` pointer with your test class, an associate the instance with the `glfwCreateWindow()` call. I'd suspect that's what these `NULL`ed parameters ar for.

Comment: window isnt the problem here, its a static void function in my class cant use anything in the class, example `private: int myWidth;`

Comment: The window is passed to your callback function and probably carries the information you provided when calling the create function. If you pass a pointer to `test` at creation, you can cast that safely back to your class type in the callback function.

Comment: i dont undestand, like whats the point of having a callback function at all then? i just need to update a set of internal variables to keep track of sizes and scales, but the only way to do it efficiently is to do it on the resize callback else im changing the values constantly.

Comment: @jeana You probably need to learn some basics about the interworkings of C++ code with C APIs before delving deeper into the specifics of how to use GLFW with c++ classes. I'm also quite sure that there will be appropriate c++ frameworks available to make that easier.

Comment: all im trying to do is reduce the global functions i have in my project, therefor i find it hard to understand that wrapping the same function in a class gives these problems